# Magento order_id increment is inconsistent(seems to have jumped one value)

Tags: magento

I have noticed that in my Orders grid in the admin, all the(hundreds) of orders have sequential order ids, all but one. I have 100000103 and then 100000105.

The 100000104 is missing. I have checked this post([magento order id increment jumps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10935117/magento-order-id-increment-jumps)) on StackOverflow, but the answer there suggests the following:

> If you want to find your 'missing' increment_ids, take a look in sales_flat_quote under the field reserved_order_id. You should see them attached to unconverted quote objects (carts).
>   But I do not have the missing ID in the specified table for the reserved_order_id column. It is also missing from there, the IDs go 103 and then 105..

I have also checked the abandoned carts reports grid, it is empty.
Should I be concerned that there was some error? The shop owner says he is worried that some order is missing or something..

Answer (score 0):

This is normal, take a look @ [magento order id increment jumps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10935117/magento-order-id-increment-jumps)

> When Magento enters the checkout process it 'reserves' an increment_id
>   and places it on the quote (cart) object and if customer change their mind there will be a missing order id.

Comment: Working as designed, the Magento design team doesn't see it as an issue.